# Alamofire sending parameter array with key and multiple value

Tags: swift, alamofire

I need to do this in my project:

multiple values in multiple array common key for parameter
[image]

Some links that have the same question but no exact answers, I always see posts that have answers like use a custom encoding and that's it.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/570

i have 4 array :

```
var imagesArray: [UIImage] = [], var DayOpreation: [String] = [],varDayOffStart: [String] = [], var DayOffEnd: [String] = []
```

and this my code :

```
let parameters : Parameters = [
        "about": self.descriptionLabel.text!,
        "address" : addressLabel.text!,
        "country" : "1",
        "state": "1",
        "city" : "1",
        "postcode" : self.postalCode.text!,
        "policies": self.policiesLabel.text,
        "longitude" : "",
        "latitude" : "",
        "available_24hours": "0",
        "open_hour" : "09:00",
        "closed_hour" : "18:00",
        "operating_days[0]": "Senin",
        "days_off[0][start]" : "2019-10-10",
        "days_off[0][end]" : "2019-10-15",
    ]
    let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultConstant.ACCESS_TOKEN)
    let headers = ["key": "\(token!)"
    ]

    let ImageData = UIImageView()
    ImageData.image = UIImage(named: "rectangle-1")
    let imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ImageData.image!)!
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "photo_profile[0]",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }
    },
                     to:"\(Endpoints.BASE)\(Endpoints.UPDATE_VENDOR)",
        method: .post,
        headers: headers,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if let data = response.data {
                        guard let json = try? JSON(data: data) else { return }
                        let messageRoom = json["message"].string
                        print("listOfficialRoom== ",json)

                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Paramaters in Alamofire, something like this

```
let daysOff = [String: Any]() // array of dictionaries for days off
for (i, day) in days.enumerated() {
    let dayOff: Parameters = [
        "start": day.start,
        "end": day.end
    ]
    daysOff["\(i)"] = dayOff
}

let parameters: Parameters = [
    "open_hour": "...",
    "closed_hour": "...",
    "days_off": daysOff
]
```

Comment: hello @Duy Le, thanks for answer. please check my update question

Comment: Can you please provide the error message or explain the exact issue?

Comment: The type of Parameters is [String : Any], so when you write "days_off[0][start]" : "2019-10-10" I think it won't recognise it as an element of the days_off array. Try building a separate array of dictionaries and pass them into the Parameter and let me know if it works. I usually use this technique and it works for me.